# Make an RPM that is for all architectures?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I have shared libraries that have `-devel` packages. These devel packages include no architecture-dependent code whatsoever.

How can I specify in the spec file that these are architecture-independent RPMs and can be installed on any architecture?

Comment: What do you mean by library and package? Conventional shared library can't have RPM package as its part, it is usually other way around.

Comment: I think this is better suited for the Unix site here.

Comment: @CharlesAddis this is definitely development/ops question, not a generic Unixx software one.

Comment: I definitely misread the question. Whoops

Answer (score 0):

No. If rpmbuild create this automatically for you then it is always arch specific.

You can create that -devel subpackage manually and specify BuildArch: noarch. But then you need to specify everything manually too. IMHO not worth the work.